# How to read configuration from appsetings.json for custom serilog sink in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, sentry, serilog

I created the custom sentry sink inside my API project.

```
public class SentrySink : ILogEventSink {...}
```

I also created an extension method for my sink so that I can connect my sink
through logging configuration.

```
 public static LoggerConfiguration Sentry(this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration, 
        string dsn, 
        string release = null, 
        string environment = null,
        LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Information, 
        IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
    {...}
```

When I use

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
               .WriteTo.Sentry(configuration["Sentry:Dsn"], restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error)
```

Everything works fine and log's are in sentry.

But when I set up the configuration in appsetting.json as

```
 "WriteTo": [
  { "Name": "Sentry" }, ...
```

without defining config in LoggerConfiguration the log's are not sent to sentry.

Do I need to implement something more so that I can use configs from appsetting.json?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include at least `"Args": {"dsn": ...}`, because the `dsn` parameter is not optional.

You may also need a `"Using": ["YourAssemblyContainingSink"]` statement to ensure the configuration method is found, depending on the deployment target, and to check that the sink assembly is copied to your project's output directory.